# substitution within a vim function using regex

Tags: function, vim

I'm trying to turn a macro into a Function. Whilst I can save the macro I'd like to make it a function I can call.

I'm de-duping a specific element in a large concatenation of xml files using the following

```
G$b"myw0"n4ywdd:264501?^Rn/\dcw^Rm^[
```

Which gets parts of the last line into registers m and n then goes to a known line above the dedupe data and searches backwards for the contents of register n and replaces the number in the line with register `m`. The known line is to make sure I find the first occurrence that's not part of the de-dedupe set. Works fine if a bit slow when running 600 times.

On the function I've managed to duplicate everything except the `cw` with the contents of register `m` part.

```
function! MakeUnique()
    let i = 0
    while i <= 1
        :200
        :let @n=""
        :let @m=""
        :normal! G
        :normal! $
        :normal! b
        :normal! "myw
        :normal! 0
        :normal! "n4yw
        :200
        execute "call search('".@n."','b')"
        let i += 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

I've tried a few combinations of substitutions along the lines of the following but with no success.

**Try 1**

Register `n` = `<dataid>389` and register `m` = `<dataid>333`

I changed the Line at the end of the file for this try to and changed `"nyw` to `ny$`

```
<dataId>333<dataid>    <dataId>389
```

I would expect that subcommand when executed would read `. s/<dataId>333/<dataId>389/`

```
let subCommand=". s/".@m"/'".@n."'/"
exec subCommand
```

But given the result it doesn't seem as if @n is expanding

```
Result:
</dataid>
```

**Try 2**

In this case `@n` = `389`

```
let subCommand=". s/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/".@n."/"
exec subCommand
```

This one works but the \d+ part may b 3 - 5 digits and I can't get a regex to work in this case, ie

```
s/\(\d\+\)/".@m."/
```

doesn't work and I get a `E486: Pattern not found d+`

**Questions:**

- Is there any way to use regex match in the `let subcommand =` bit eg `let subCommand = ". s/\d+/".@n"/"`
- Alternatively how do I replace using something like

  ```
  let subCommand=". s/".@m"/'".@n."'/"
  ```
- Or is there a vimscript equivalent of `cw^Rm` ?

**Data example, cut down to fit.**

The first iteration of the macro will change `6415` to `8790` in the identified line below.

I'm trying to replicate that in a Function.

```js
1    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
2    <createsaleRequest>
3        <sale>
4            <saleNumber>9987166</saleNumber>
5            <dataId>6315</dataId>
6        </sale>
7        ...
8    </createsaleRequest>
9
10
11    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
12    <createsaleRequest>
13        <sale>
14            <saleNumber>9988166</saleNumber>
15            <dataId>6415</dataId>
16        </sale>
17        ...
18    </createsaleRequest>
19
20    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
21    <createsaleRequest>
22        <sale>
23            <saleNumber>9987921</saleNumber>
24            <dataId>6315</dataId>
25        </sale>
26        ...
27    </createsaleRequest>
28
29
30    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
31    <createsaleRequest>
32        <sale>
33            <saleNumber>9987411</saleNumber>
34            <dataId>6415</dataId> <!-- Change this on first run through -->
35        </sale>
36        ...
37    </createsaleRequest>
38
39    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
40    <createsaleRequest>
41        <sale>
42            <saleNumber>9987411</saleNumber>
43            <dataId>6193</dataId>
44        </sale>
45        ...
46    </createsaleRequest>
47
48
49
50
51    <dataId>6315</dataId> 6789
52    <dataId>6415</dataId> 8790
```

**EDIT**
Added a cut down data example to try and make the question make sense.

**Edit**
Found the problem. I'd left the second `.` out of the match portion. This `let subCommand=". s/".@m."/".@n."/"`works and is significantly faster than the macro. Don't know how to close the question.

I would like to know what ". ." means. I'm guessing it's an escape pattern that works in vimscript.

Comment: I don't really get how you are able to extract the string `<dataid>389` from the line `<dataid>333</dataid>`. Can you provide us a more realistic sample?

Comment: That particular one I changed the dedupe line to read <dataid>333</dataid>\t<dataid>389. Then yanked  <dataid>389 to register n. I'll edit the question when I get home.  The example is real with element names changed